# Raw query with multiple parameters

Tags: android, sqlite

PREF_NAME, PREF_STATUS - text

It gives me this error:

```
07-02 14:08:07.457: E/AndroidRuntime(17295): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = ?
```

The code I'm using is:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = ?", new String[]{ PREF_STATUS,
   PREF_TABLE, PREF_NAME, assigned_pref_name });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), you only can put "?" on where clause:

```
public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)

Parameters
sql the SQL query. The SQL string must not be ; terminated
selectionArgs   You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.
```

Comment: Lol .. i read this given link at least twice, but it seems that I wasn't paying attention. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After the `SELECT` keyword you have a `?` instead of something like `*`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to pass assigned_pref_name as a string and not variable name so :

```
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
              "SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = ?",
                new String[]{
                PREF_STATUS,
                PREF_TABLE,
                PREF_NAME, 
                "assigned_pref_name" //as a string 
          });
```